# HTML output not being displayed correctly in JEditorPane

Tags: java, html, swing, jeditorpane

I have two tables that are supposed to be side by side on the same line.

One table ("stableTable") is always on the right side of the viewable area, and the other table ("movingTable") can be modified to have its align be left, center or right.

Here's the HTML Code

```html
<html>
<head>
<!--Test Header-->
<style>
body {display: inline; width: auto;}
table {width: auto;}
table, th, tr, td {border: 1px solid;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="stableTable" align="right">
    <tr>
    <td>
    WORLD
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="movingTable" align="right">
    <tr>
    <td>
    HELLO
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

When I put this in an HTML file and open the browser it shows up correctly as seen below (both side by side):

[image]

But here's the output when I put this same HTML code in a JEditorPane (one is on top of the other):
[image]

I'm stumped on this one as I have tried different things in an HTML file that appears correct when I open it up on a browser, but it doesn't in the Java JEditorPane.

Any thoughts?

EDIT:
After looking online a little, it appears that Java has a poor track record for rendering HTML and CSS correctly.  I found an article that mentioned downloading flyingsaucer jar file (I ended up downloading the flying-saucer-core-9.0.4.jar version) and it appears to render the HTML side by side as I wanted.

Now my only task is to get it to work within the existing maven project I'm working in with the actual tables.

Comment: Thanks! I'll just answer the question with the quoted text in your first comment, that way if someone else runs into this same issue they can see this as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue here is with the JEditorPane itself and that it (and Java itself) has a poor track record of rendering HTML/CSS.

I have found that using flying saucer 3rd party app is the way to go.  I have tested with that and it does render the HTML as I want.

Here's the link to the specific flying saucer version that I used https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xhtmlrenderer/flying-saucer-core/9.0.4